# help with accessing variables inside of my class

Tags: php, oop

Hmmm, so how is this done?

I have a class

```
class Themes extends Access
{
    public $theme_name;
    public $theme_by;
    public $theme_by_email;
    public $theme_by_website;
    public $theme_description;
    public $theme_thumb;
    public $theme_source;
    public $theme_uploaded_on;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        //$this->get_theme();
    }

    public function get_theme()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT *
                FROM `user_themes`
                WHERE `user_id` = " . $this->session->get('user_id');
        if($this->db->row_count($sql))
        {
            $result            = $this->db->fetch_row_assoc($sql);
            $this->$theme_name        = $result['theme_name'];
            $theme_by          = $result['theme_by'];
            $theme_by_email    = $result['theme_by_email'];
            $theme_by_website  = $result['theme_by_website'];
            $theme_description = $result['theme_description'];
            $theme_source      = $result['theme_source'];
            $theme_uploaded_on = $result['theme_uploaded_on'];
        }else{
            die('no results');
        }
    }
}
```

How can I access these variables and their contents outside of the class?

in my PHP page I have

```
$theme = new Themes();
```

I tried to access my variable using

`$theme->them_name` but I get an undefined error

but don't really know how I can access the variable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your current setup, all you have to do is call:

```
$theme->theme_name;
$theme->theme_by;
etc
```

However it is generally not good practice to make instance variables public, rather make them private and make [mutator methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method).

An example would be:

```
private $theme_name;

public function getThemeName(){
  return $this->theme_name;
}

public function setThemeName($theme){
  $this->theme_name = $theme;
}
```

Comment: I thought about that, but I didn't want to have to make 7 calls to the database just to get the info i needed

Comment: You don't have to. You can call $theme->get_theme(), which will be your only DB call. After that, use the mutator methods. Some added benefit for using something like setThemeName, you can add optional validation before setting that value.

Comment: um, a little confused, where is $theme being called from?

Comment: For example. $theme = new Theme(); $theme->setTheme("random theme name");

Comment: oh, well in this case the theme is already in the database, so the get_theme() is calling out all the data and placing them in variables so in my application i can reference the data. like <p>Theme by: $theme-theme_by</p>

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->theme_name        = $result['theme_name'];
$this->theme_by          = $result['theme_by'];
```

Note on `$this` prepended.

After that you can access the data using `$theme->theme_name` etc